# Learning from distance matrices

Tags: classification, distance, similarities, multi-class

I have a task to build **multi-task classification model based on distance (similarity) matrix only**. They are already precalculated and no changes here can be applied.

Can you, please, recommend me where to look for more? articles, packages? any approach that start from distance matrix and set of classes?

I tried to do that with kNN via approach mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675570/nearest-neighbors-in-python-given-the-distance-matrix), but results are not very satisfactory. I would be glad to use SVM-like and/or ANN-like algorithm. They are mostly better than kNN.

Comment: You must give more context. What else do you know about the data? How big is the distance matrix? You want a classification. ¿Do you know class membership in some cases? without more context not much can be said!

Comment: the matrix is around 500k, it's around 400 classes, some entries can belong to several binary classes (yes/no). The entries are 3D objects, the similarity was pre-calculated not by me.